# How to replace PDF page

Tags: pdf, edit, asp.net-core-3.1

Given a `PDF` (with multiple pages), a page (`stream`) and a index , how can i replace the page at target `index` with my stream and save the pdf ?

```
public Stream ReplacePDFPageAtIndex(Stream pdfStream,int index,Stream replacePageStream)
{
      List<Stream> pdfPages= //fetch pdf pages
      pdfPages.RemoveAt(index);
      pdfPages.Insert(index,replacePageStream);
      Stream newPdf=//create new pdf using the edited list
      return newPdf;
}
```

I was wondering if there is any open source solution or i can roll my own with ease , given the fact that i just need to split the pdf in pages , and replace one of them.
I have also checked `ITextSharp` but i do not see the functionality that i require.

Comment: Try googling for itextsharp split merge pdf.

Comment: What kind of *streams* do you expect to be able to pack pdf pages in? Many objects in a pdf may be used on multiple pages, a pdf page often is not an isolated entity.

Comment: I understand , i am not aware of the internals of a pdf stream. I just want to edit a pdf page (rotate it by a given angle) , save the change in the original pdf and send the stream back.

Comment: What you need to do is to load the pdf file, rotate de page and then save the file. Almost any pdf library can do this.